# Обратиться к строке двумерного массива

Tags: c#

Допустим инициализировали двумерный массив

```
string[,] arr = {
                    {"1", "2", "3"},
                    {"4", "5", "6"},
                    {"7", "8", "9"},
                    {"10", "11", "12"}
                };
```

Возможно ли как нибудь обратиться к строке массива, как к одномерному массиву?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нет, так сделать нельзя.

Но можно написать обертку, которая будет "выглядеть" как одномерный массив. Например, так:

```
public struct ArrayRow<T> {
    private readonly T[,] array;
    private readonly int row;
    public ArrayRow(T[,] array, int row) {
        this.array = array;
        this.row = row;
    }

    public int Length {
        get { return array.GetLength(1); }
    }

    public T this[int column] {
        get { return array[row, column]; }
        set { array[row, column] = value; }
    }
}
```

Однако подобную структуру, хотя она и похожа на массив, нельзя передавать вместо массива.

Тем не менее, если дописать ещё коду, можно сделать эту структуру реализующей интерфейс `IList<T>`, который массивы реализуют тоже - это позволит использовать один и тот же код для работы как с обычными массивами, так и с подобными срезами.

Answer (score 4):

Многомерные массивы хранятся в памяти как один непрерывный одномерный массив. При обращении по индексу `[i, j]` вычисляется конкретная позиция в этом внутреннем одномерном массиве и возвращается значение.

Так как внутреннего представления в виде отдельных массивов нет, то и обратится к ним нельзя. Единственный способ получить одномерный массив - создать его вручную и скопировать туда значения, но при этом это будет именно копия массива, с отдельными элементами.

Comment: А через ссылки возможно как нибудь?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что как-то извернуться можно, хотя да, нормального способа нет.

Comment: За ссылки в шарпе могут и побить =D. А если серьезно - может вам  изначально представить данные в виде одномерного массива? Четные значения - измерение 1 а нечетные - измерение 2. Одномерные массивы обрабатываются быстрее, поэтому такой способ распространен например для представления массивов координат и геоданных (X,Y).

Comment: @e1s единственное, чем могут помочь ссылки - это если сами элементы массива - ссылочные типы, И вы используете / меняете их содержимое (т.е. не используете `a[x] = myObj`, а обращаетесь через свойства/методы, например `a[x].myProp = 18`); но в этом случае всё равно надо сначала создать отдельную копию куска многомерного массива

Answer (score 2):

А такой вариант не годится?

```
string[][] arr = new string[][] {
                     new string[] {"1", "2", "3"},
                     new string[] {"4", "5", "6"},
                     new string[] {"7", "8", "9"},
                     new string[] {"10", "11", "12"}
                 };
```

Comment: Спасибо за вариант, такой я рассматривал, по сути это "рваный массив" или массив массивов, а речь  про двумерный

Comment: @e1s, да. Но ты как раз хочешь к строке как к одномерному обратиться - в этом случае рваный вместо двумерного кажется более подходящим.