# Неверное количество индексов в массиве

Tags: c#, массивы

Задача из двумерного массива вытаскивать его элементы в виде массивов.

```
//объявили двумерный массив.
int[,] array2d = {{1,2,3},{2,3,4},{3,4,5}};
//надо сохранить первый элемент {1,2,3} в переменную.
int[] array1d = array2d[0];
```

И получаем следующую ошибку:

> Неверное число индексов в массиве[] требуется 2

Я так понимаю обязательно надо указывать оба индекса.

Вопрос: Как в таком случае получить любой подмассив из двумерного массива по номеру элемента?

Comment: Вам нужен массив массивов, а не двумерный массив

Comment: пояснение к тексту @АндрейNOP `int[][]` а не `int[,]`

Comment: [Обратиться к строке двумерного массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446651/178779)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже написали в комментариях, для этой цели проще использовать массив массивов, а не многомерный массив:

```
int[][] array2d = new int[][] {new[]{1,2,3}, new[]{2,3,4}, new[]{3,4,5}};
int[] array1d = array2d[0];
```

Если нужно вытащить строку именно 2D-массива, то, боюсь, удобного способа нет. Неудобные способы перечислены в похожем вопросе на английском: [How to get a complete row or column from 2D array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27427527/how-to-get-a-complete-row-or-column-from-2d-array-in-c-sharp).

В частности, [@ShimonDoodkin предлагает](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27427527/how-to-get-a-complete-row-or-column-from-2d-array-in-c-sharp#42321633) метод-расширение:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static T[] GetRow<T>(this T[,] array, int wanted_row)
    {
        int l = array.GetLength(1);
        T[] row = new T[l];
        for(int i=0; i<l; i++)
        {
          row[i] = array[wanted_row,i];
        }
        return row;
    }
}
```

, который можно будет использовать так:

```
int[,] array2d = {{1,2,3},{2,3,4},{3,4,5}};
//надо сохранить первый элемент {1,2,3} в переменную.
int[] array1d = array2d.GetRow(0);
```